# Help deploying apex trigger into production

Tags: trigger, change-set

So attempting to deploy my trigger into production

I've created a test class and I got 100% coverage.

[image]

When I create a change and and deploy it from production I am getting these errors.
Not sure what it means and its referring to other classes but Im sure my trigger has nothing to do with these.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: `KnowledgeArticleVersion.ArticleType` was introduced in v26. Do those classes that report errors use a version pre V26.0?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are related to Salesforce Knowledge and indeed happen on code that's already in production. It is not at all related to your new code.

You could try running all test classes in production and then report that to whoever is maintaining production because it needs to be fixed there if it's blocking new deployments.

Theoretically this could be due to missing authorizations for the user doing the deployment. In that case, a possible workaround might be to activate Salesforce Knowledge for your user.

Another possible workaround could be to only run the specific test class that tests your new trigger. You can select that option when doing a deployment into production. This will prevent all the other test classes from running, and so the errors will not occur. It will not structurally resolve the issue of all these test classes failing on production.